# Fastest way to parse combinations of words in a string in python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, combinations

new to Python. I need to parse a body of text and check if an element in a dict exists in that body. So far I've come up with using itertools:

```
from string import punctuation
from itertools import combinations

def retrieve_text_from_body(body, dict):
  a_list = []
  stripped_body = [i.strip(punctuation) for i in body.split()]
    for i in range(1, len(stripped_body)+1):
        for combination in combinations(stripped_body, i):
            if combination in dict:
                a_list.append(dict[combination])
  return a_list
```

Example input and output:

```
Body = "The big fat cat sits" (Could be up to 1000 words)
Dict = ["Big Fat", "Little Mouse", "Cat Sits"] (Could be any length)

Part of combinations that form:
['the', 'big']
['the', 'big', 'fat']
['the', 'big', 'fat', 'cat']
['the', 'big', 'fat', 'cat', 'sits']
['big', 'fat']
['big', 'fat', 'cat']
['big', 'fat', 'cat', 'sits']

Output: ["Big Fat", "Cat Sits"]
```

The code above is just very slow in my usecase since I have to do it across millions of rows in a table. I'm wondering if there is a faster approach?

Comment: "The code above is just very slow in my usecase since I have to do it across millions of rows in a table" What exactly is being implemented? What is in the `body` and `dict` passed to the function, and what is actually being output as a result - what is the **pattern** in these outputs?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Hint: if there are 1000 words in `Body`, how many different combinations of any number of words do you think could be generated? (If you can't easily answer this, then you should study the underlying theory, and you may really have a math question rather than a programming question.) Meanwhile, how long is `Dict` likely to be?

Comment: Yes I see your point. Dict has ~70K entries. So for every entry in dict, search if it exists in body instead of pursue combination route? Body is on average ~20-30 words.

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: _" I need to parse a body of text and check if an element in a dict exists in that body"_ ... this is roughly a substring search - why did you come up with combinations? It seems your problem description is skimming some important details.

Comment: Will you also accept "fat big", "mouse little", ... ?

Comment: Do the expressions in the dict have may words in common ?

Comment: Expressions in the dict may not have a lot of words in common and it won't accept "fat big". Substring search is just combinations except I'm doing it across words and not characters? I don't have a specific window of words (variable length)

Comment: It's not clear under what conditions you consider a two-word phrase to exist in the body.  For "Cat Sits", do "Cat" and Sits" have to appear consecutively in the body?  Please [edit] your question to specify the problem more precisely. Please don't leave clarifications in the comments -- instead, [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching each combination of (any number of) 30 words in a list of 70k strings. The number of generated combinations is `2**30`, or around 1 billion, so you are performing 1 billion searches on 70k items - since most of the searches will fail, we can say you are performing around 70k billions comparisons. Yes, it will take ages - the time complexity is `O(2**w * s)`, i.e. worse than exponential. Let's make a totally arbitrary hypothesis, and say it takes one day to perform this.

One better-performing approach would be sorting your dict before, and then use a binary search. Still 1 billion of combinations to check, but at least the search is logarithmic in time, so we have now around 16 billion (slightly slower, let's say 1.5x) comparisons, and a time complexity `O(2**w * log s)`. Still not what we're looking for, but instead of one day we would now spend some 30 seconds (plus the initial sort, but the overhead is irrelevant)

If you can change your dict datatype, convert the list of strings in a *set* of strings. This way you have O(1) search time, so just `O(2**w)` overall. Still exponential, but the 30 seconds above now become 1.25.

The other way to attain a dramatic change of speed, of course, is to reverse the logic. Do not create the combos, and for each dict entry simply check if it's in the body : `O(s * w)`. Unfortunately we cannot use here the "set" optimization, however with your data this solution should be about 4 times faster than the set-based one, so our 1.25 secs are now 0.3 or so.

Just to have an idea of the actual run time we could expect I did the following

```
bigdict = list(range(70000))
words=list(range(100000,100030)) #worst case: no word is in bigdict
timeit('for b in bigdict:x=b in words', globals=globals(), number=1)
0.021891699987463653
```

Answer (score -1):

With regex, you can solve this problem in a simple way. It is true that regexes are quite slow as they work by accessing all positions of the string multiple times.

```py
import regex as re

def search_in_body(body, structures):
    found_structures = [
        f for f in structures if re.search(f, body, re.IGNORECASE)
    ]
    return found_structures


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Body = "The big fat cat sits"
    Dict = ["Big Fat", "Little Mouse", "Cat Sits"] 
    print(search_in_body(Body, Dict))
```

```bash
>>> ['Big Fat', 'Cat Sits']
```

Comment: Tried the method, but got the error: `regex._regex_core.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 1`. Even after removing all punctuation.